# How to make a div to have same height to one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to push height of a div to equal to other div. 
In my case, I have 2 div: div one and div two. I need to push height of div two to equal div one. No matter content on div two, the height will equal to div one. If content on div two longer than content on div one, it will overflow the div two. Like the described bellow:

[image]

Is it possible to use jquery, CSS or combine of them?
I am trying some answer from other question here, but most different case. Most of question here about equal between 2 div, not equal to one div.

Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: you can do it with only css use same class for both with width a and height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with only css

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
.mydiv
{
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
 overflow: scroll;
 border:2px solid black;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
}

#one{
 left: 10px;

}

#two{
 left:220px;
}

</style>

<body>


<div class="mydiv" id="one">kjfkdfjdkfjkfjdkfjk  jfkdjfdkfj kdfj kjfkfj kdjfkdfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjkdfjdkfjdkfja ldjfdk jdkf jdkfjdk jfkdjfdk jkdjfkdjfkdjfkdjfkdfjdkfj kdjkdjfkdjfkdfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjkdfjk
</div>
<div class="mydiv" id="two">
kdlfjdlfa;fj jfaljfkdlfjd jjf ljfal jljfafj dj djajfafajfdljadflkdjfldfjlfjdfjdkfjdslfjdlkfjdfkdjfdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkjfkdjfkjfkjfkdjfkdfjkfjdkjfkdjfkdfjkdlfjdlfa;fj jfaljfkdlfjd jjf ljfal jljfafj dj djajfafajfdljadflkdjfldfjlfjdfjdkfjdslfjdlkfjdfkdjfdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkjfkdjfkjfkjfkdjfkdfjkfjdkjfkdjfkdfjkdlfjdlfa;fj jfaljfkdlfjd jjf ljfal jljfafj dj djajfafajfdljadflkdjfldfjlfjdfjdkfjdslfjdlkfjdfkdjfdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkjfkdjfkjfkjfkdjfkdfjkfjdkjfkdjfkdfjkdlfjdlfa;fj jfaljfkdlfjd jjf ljfal jljfafj dj djajfafajfdljadflkdjfldfjlfjdfjdkfjdslfjdlkfjdfkdjfdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkjfkdjfkjfkjfkdjfkdfjkfjdkjfkdjfkdfjkdlfjdlfa;fj jfaljfkdlfjd jjf ljfal jljfafj dj djajfafajfdljadflkdjfldfjlfjdfjdkfjdslfjdlkfjdfkdjfdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkjfkdjfkjfkjfkdjfkdfjkfjdkjfkdjfkdfjkdlfjdlfa;fj jfaljfkdlfjd jjf ljfal jljfafj dj djajfafajfdljadflkdjfldfjlfjdfjdkfjdslfjdlkfjdfkdjfdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkjfkdjfkjfkjfkdjfkdfjkfjdkjfkdjfkdfjkdlfjdlfa;fj jfaljfkdlfjd jjf ljfal jljfafj dj djajfafajfdljadflkdjfldfjlfjdfjdkfjdslfjdlkfjdfkdjfdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkjfkdjfkjfkjfkdjfkdfjkfjdkjfkdjfkdfjkdlfjdlfa;fj jfaljfkdlfjd jjf ljfal jljfafj dj djajfafajfdljadflkdjfldfjlfjdfjdkfjdslfjdlkfjdfkdjfdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkjfkdjfkjfkjfkdjfkdfjkfjdkjfkdjfkdfjkdlfjdlfa;fj jfaljfkdlfjd jjf ljfal jljfafj dj djajfafajfdljadflkdjfldfjlfjdfjdkfjdslfjdlkfjdfkdjfdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkjfkdjfkjfkjfkdjfkdfjkfjdkjfkdjfkdfjkdlfjdlfa;fj jfaljfkdlfjd jjf ljfal jljfafj dj djajfafajfdljadflkdjfldfjlfjdfjdkfjdslfjdlkfjdfkdjfdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkjfkdjfkjfkjfkdjfkdfjkfjdkjfkdjfkdfjkdlfjdlfa;fj jfaljfkdlfjd jjf ljfal jljfafj dj djajfafajfdljadflkdjfldfjlfjdfjdkfjdslfjdlkfjdfkdjfdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkjfkdjfkjfkjfkdjfkdfjkfjdkjfkdjfkdfjkdlfjdlfa;fj jfaljfkdlfjd jjf ljfal jljfafj dj djajfafajfdljadflkdjfldfjlfjdfjdkfjdslfjdlkfjdfkdjfdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkjfkdjfkjfkjfkdjfkdfjkfjdkjfkdjfkdfj
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">





</script>
</body>

</html>
```

**or using jquery**

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>

.mydiv{
 overflow: scroll;
 border:2px solid black;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
}

#one{
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
}

#two{
 left:220px;
}

</style>

<body>


<div class="mydiv" id="one">kjfkdfjdkfjkfjdkfjk  jfkdjfdkfj kdfj kjfkfj kdjfkdfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjkdfjdkfjdkfja ldjfdk jdkf jdkfjdk jfkdjfdk jkdjfkdjfkdjfkdjfkdfjdkfj kdjkdjfkdjfkdfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjkdfjk
</div>
<div class="mydiv" id="two">
kdlfjdlfa;fj jfaljfkdlfjd jjf ljfal jljfafj dj djajfafajfdljadflkdjfldfjlfjdfjdkfjdslfjdlkfjdfkdjfdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkjfkdjfkjfkjfkdjfkdfjkfjdkjfkdjfkdfjkdlfjdlfa;fj jfaljfkdlfjd jjf ljfal jljfafj dj djajfafajfdljadflkdjfldfjlfjdfjdkfjdslfjdlkfjdfkdjfdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkjfkdjfkjfkjfkdjfkdfjkfjdkjfkdjfkdfjkdlfjdlfa;fj jfaljfkdlfjd jjf ljfal jljfafj dj djajfafajfdljadflkdjfldfjlfjdfjdkfjdslfjdlkfjdfkdjfdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkjfkdjfkjfkjfkdjfkdfjkfjdkjfkdjfkdfjkdlfjdlfa;fj jfaljfkdlfjd jjf ljfal jljfafj dj djajfafajfdljadflkdjfldfjlfjdfjdkfjdslfjdlkfjdfkdjfdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkjfkdjfkjfkjfkdjfkdfjkfjdkjfkdjfkdfjkdlfjdlfa;fj jfaljfkdlfjd jjf ljfal jljfafj dj djajfafajfdljadflkdjfldfjlfjdfjdkfjdslfjdlkfjdfkdjfdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkjfkdjfkjfkjfkdjfkdfjkfjdkjfkdjfkdfjkdlfjdlfa;fj jfaljfkdlfjd jjf ljfal jljfafj dj djajfafajfdljadflkdjfldfjlfjdfjdkfjdslfjdlkfjdfkdjfdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkjfkdjfkjfkjfkdjfkdfjkfjdkjfkdjfkdfjkdlfjdlfa;fj jfaljfkdlfjd jjf ljfal jljfafj dj djajfafajfdljadflkdjfldfjlfjdfjdkfjdslfjdlkfjdfkdjfdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkjfkdjfkjfkjfkdjfkdfjkfjdkjfkdjfkdfjkdlfjdlfa;fj jfaljfkdlfjd jjf ljfal jljfafj dj djajfafajfdljadflkdjfldfjlfjdfjdkfjdslfjdlkfjdfkdjfdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkjfkdjfkjfkjfkdjfkdfjkfjdkjfkdjfkdfjkdlfjdlfa;fj jfaljfkdlfjd jjf ljfal jljfafj dj djajfafajfdljadflkdjfldfjlfjdfjdkfjdslfjdlkfjdfkdjfdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkjfkdjfkjfkjfkdjfkdfjkfjdkjfkdjfkdfjkdlfjdlfa;fj jfaljfkdlfjd jjf ljfal jljfafj dj djajfafajfdljadflkdjfldfjlfjdfjdkfjdslfjdlkfjdfkdjfdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkjfkdjfkjfkjfkdjfkdfjkfjdkjfkdjfkdfjkdlfjdlfa;fj jfaljfkdlfjd jjf ljfal jljfafj dj djajfafajfdljadflkdjfldfjlfjdfjdkfjdslfjdlkfjdfkdjfdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkjfkdjfkjfkjfkdjfkdfjkfjdkjfkdjfkdfjkdlfjdlfa;fj jfaljfkdlfjd jjf ljfal jljfafj dj djajfafajfdljadflkdjfldfjlfjdfjdkfjdslfjdlkfjdfkdjfdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkfjdkjfkdjfkjfkjfkdjfkdfjkfjdkjfkdjfkdfj
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

var div_one_width = $("#one").width(); //get the first div width
var div_one_height = $("#one").height(); // get the second div height.
$("#two").css({"width":div_one_width+'px',"height":div_one_height+'px'})



</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am using your jquery code without the width. Work perfectly as I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
 window.onload=function()
 {
          $(div2 selector).css("height",$(div1 selector).css("height"));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

With pure Javascript, you can use the [element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) method on your DIV#1 to get its real height value. Then apply it to DIV#2 CSS style:

```
var div1_height = document.querySelector("#div1").getBoundingClientRect().height;
document.querySelector("#div2").style.height = div1_height+"px";
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the id of the div to which your div should be and set the height of your div to it.

Eg class div1 is the div with smaller size &
Class div2 is the div whose size you need to change to div1 's size do this :

```
$('.div2').attr('height',$('.div1').attr('height'));
```